# Populate Ember Data from MySQL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a working version using Mirage, but now I need to get my app working with my real database. I already wrote the script that returns the JSON (2 versions: PHP and Go).

1. Where should I store the script?
2. How do I get my route to populate Ember Data using the script?

I've Googled and fiddled for days with no success. This is driving me crazy, so thank you for any help!

Comment: What do you mean with "middle man" file? I thought you want to get the data from your database - via a php script I suppose.

Comment: I'm new, so my terminology sucks. The "middle man" file is a PHP file that queries my database and returns (echo json_encode) the object I want. I'm having trouble getting that object into my Ember Data store.

Comment: then you should read this introduction of ember (data) about how to get the data from the server: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/

Comment: Your php script needs to return json that ember-data can understand, either json that the RESTAdapter or JSONAPIAdapter can understand. Check out the server implementations of JSONAPI in PHP (http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-php). As for hosting your PHP backend, you'll need to do that on a server some where. Simple shared hosting that supports PHP and a Mysql database should be enough to get you started.